# What's the best way to set Cache-Control headers in Apache2?

Tags: apache-2.4, cache, http-headers

[Under this link](http://www.askapache.com/hacking/speed-site-caching-cache-control.html) you have some examples on how to set `Cache-Control` headers in Apache2 server. So generally, there are three different approaches to have these headers set:

1. Using both `mod_expires` + `mod_headers`
2. Using only `mod_headers`
3. Using only `mod_expires`

Are there any significant differences between them? Which one is the preferred one and why, or maybe it doesn't matter at all? What's the best way to set `Cache-Control` headers in Apache2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is that [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html) will not replace/update `Cache-Control`  headers if an `Expires` header has already been set by your web application or script and can't really be used to set anything besides the `max-age` Cache Control header.

The [`Header`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header) directive from [mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) on the other hand  can be configured to not be as considerate and will also happily merge or completely replace any existing headers to new headers you specify.  That allows you to override whatever (default and not configurable) `Cache-Control` headers your web applications or scripts set, as well as set any other headers.

As far as I know mod_headers does not provide an interface to  do the calculations that mod_expires does to calculate future dates i.e to set the Expires header to a time stamp of `now + 1 month` you can't use the Header directive.

So the modules are complementary.

Comment: Good answer. Also mod_headers is needed to add the directives other than max-age (e.g. public, private, no-store...etc.) as shown in OPs original link. This is, as you state, to compliment max-age set by mod_expires.